# I am having issue in using itertuples in dataframe. I can use sumifs in excel however here I m trying to use itertuples but the amount is not correct

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sumifs

I am trying to populate a column in dataframe with the data available in another dataframe. However when I am using the following code it gets me the same amount for each row however it should  be different for each row.
The code is as below:

```
for row in df.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):
    df['Purchases']=df1.loc[(df1['CUSIP']==row[2]) & (df1['SSB_FUND']==row[1]) & (df1['REP_TITLE']=='Purchases Report'),'SHARESPAR'].sum()
```

I am getting following output :

```
 FUND   CUSIP       Purchase    
 2CK7   517834107   42750.0 
 2X25   31315KFC9   42750.0 
 2X25   31315KFF2   42750.0 
 2X25   31315KFJ4   42750.0
```

However only the last has 42750 value in reality and othet cusips have different value. 
Just to give you my objective I am trying to pull total purchase for cusips for each individual fund which can be done by sumifs in excel.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Kindly share a sample of ur original data frame with expected output

Comment: You should never change a dataframe while iterating over its rows ([see the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)), they state "You should never modify something you are iterating over. This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no effect."

Comment: @sammywemmy how do I share with my data its a big one